# Proper way to do HTTPS for Apache on localhost [Windows]?

Tags: apache-http-server, openssl

Through this [How do I allow HTTPS for Apache on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7184031) answer I easily converted http://localhost to https://localhost but I am not getting the correct display name as shown in the below image.

This is my localhost

[image]

This is how PayPal url looks

[image]

What am I missing or its only possible through actual certificate from some vendors?

Comment: Those names are only displayed by the browser when you present a valid [EV certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate). Is there a specific reason that you want to have an EV cert for localhost?

Comment: No, as I was doing experiment with these and not getting such display so thought might be doing something wrong or it's not possible, that's why I aksed, thanks to clear my thoughts!

Comment: Also note... EV Certificates do not provide any additional security controls. They are overpriced DV Certificates. The Browsers and CA's collude at the [CA/Browser Forum](https://cabforum.org/), and EV Certificates are one of the things that dropped out. It helps restore CA profit levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of certificate you're looking for is an Extended Validation certificate. These certificates go through some extra validation (hence the 'extended') before being issued by the CA.

According to [This answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/48129/304306), the only way to get an EV certificate is by going to a CA that is allowed to issue them, and have them issue you one. The process for obtaining an EV certificate takes longer than a standard DV (Domain Validation) certificate, because the CA will research your company and make sure that you are requesting the certificate for a domain that actually belongs to the company.

As far as I know, you can't create your own EV certificates and expect browsers to trust them. Even if you install the certificates on your system.

[Wikipedia article about EV certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate)

**TL;DR:** For as far as I know, the only way for you to get an EV certificate (and with that, to have the browser to display the company name next to the padlock) is to go to an official CA and purchase one from them. You cannot purchase an EV certificate for localhost because it's not a public domain.

You cannot get a better certificate for localhost than you have now.